# Load mantine styles after Tailwind preflight

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, mantine

I'm trying to use Mantine and Tailwind together, however Tailwind's "preflight" base styles are overriding Mantine's resulting in a simple button being invisible.

[image]

You can disable preflight:

```
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: true
  }
```

But I'd rather keep it enabled and load Mantine CSS after, per [this suggestion](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/6602#issuecomment-1050099984).

Is there any way to specify order for this?

Comment: This GH issue might be relevant to your issue: https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/823.

Answer (score 9):

Create an Emotion cache using `createEmotionCache` from Mantine core, and set `prepend` to `false`. Then, call it inside `MantineProvider`'s `emotionCache` prop:

```
import {
  MantineProvider,
  createEmotionCache
} from '@mantine/core';

const myCache = createEmotionCache({
  key: 'mantine',
  prepend: false
});

<MantineProvider emotionCache={myCache}>{children}</MantineProvider>
```

Comment: When using this solution, it causes layout shift (my CSS jumps) when the page is loaded initially, seems like the emotionCache is loaded in afterwards...

Comment: this solution still doesn't work when deploying to production (without the preflight fix above)

Comment: It starts working after enabling both fixes (disable preflight and this one)

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:
Add `preflight: false` in `tailwind.config.js` to disable the default

Copy out https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.2.4/src/css/preflight.css refereed by https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight and import it in your entry point

Comment: module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false // avoid conflict with mantine theming, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083381/load-mantine-styles-after-tailwind-preflight
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

Comment: @Pencilcheck not sure what are you talking about...

Comment: I tried to copy the content of my tailwind config how preflight disable looks

Comment: Another method to fix this issue is to add your own mantine emotion cache and disable prepend: https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/823

Comment: This looked promising but didn't help. I tried `preflight: false` and replacing `@import 'tailwind';` with `@import 'tailwindcss/lib/css/preflight.css'`. It found that file successfully, but my styles are pretty messed up.

Answer (score 2):

So, in your global stylesheet where you imported the tailwind styles remove the base styles as they will override some mantine styles. It should look like this

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 2):

My SCSS is:

```scss
/* styles/globals.scss */
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer tailwind {
  @tailwind base;
}
```

And I do *not* disable `preflight` in `tailwind.config.ts`.

See https://github.com/orgs/mantinedev/discussions/1672.

Comment: Works with Mantine v5. I tried it on v7 and it did not work. My tailwind.css file was a normal css file, not a scss.

Comment: @Zxeenu Mine is `  "@mantine/core": "^7.2.1", "@mantine/hooks": "^7.2.1",` with `"tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",`.

Comment: I tried it with ```"tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"``` and ```"@mantine/core": "^7.3.0"```, the Mantine Group and Grid weren't working right. The tailwind base styles were overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by changing the order of **'globals.css'** and **'@mantine/core/styles.css'**.

Below is the code sample:

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import '@mantine/core/styles.css'; // import before globals.css
import './globals.css'
import { MantineProvider, ColorSchemeScript } from '@mantine/core';
import { Providers } from './providers';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
```

Here you can read more
[Mantine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkkA6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution to get it to work inside index.css add these

```
@layer base {
button[type="button"]:where([data-active]) {
    background-color: #2563eb;
}
```

}